# How do I style code I made in JS? (Like the date or google map)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles

In this case I'm spefically talking about the date cause thats the problem I'm facing now I don't have a CLUEEEE as to how to change the color or place it somewhere so it doesn't look dumb, also since I feel like I'll have a problem putting the map in using jquery will be a problem too. not necessary to answer but a tip or link to a relevant tut would be nice since I can't find any good ones.

`enter code here`http://codepen.io/admitdefeat/pen/WxKmYk

see its on the left...
i'd like to put in the BOTTOM RIGHT.

Comment: what is the role of *1 in this code  `(month * 1) + 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you code in a element and style that

```
document.write("<div style='color:red;float:right;margin-right:15px;'>",month,"/",day,"/",year,"</div>");
```

You can't style text, you can only style the parent element of the text,so to separate the text from the rest of the page you warp it in a page